# TS: How to make returning type be a type of interface property with enum keys

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-types

My goal is to make a set-method with prop_key and prop_value arguments that decide a type of prop_value on the value of a prop_key.

I want it to use enum as prop names and an interface as types of prop values.

What I want to do:

```
enum Property {
  A = 0,
  B,
  C
}

interface PropertyStorage {
  [Properties.A]: number;
  [Properties.B]: string;
  [Properties.C]: boolean;
}

setProperty(name: Property, value: TypeOfThisPropertyInStorage?): void 

// Example
// setProterty(Propert.A, value => number)
// setProterty(Property.B, value => string)
// setProterty(Property.C, value => boolean)
```

Recently I've tried:

```
setProperty(name: Property, value: Pick<PropertyStorage , typeof name>): void
```

But when I try to use it I get:

```
setProperty(Property.A, 15) 
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<PropertyStorage , Property>'.
```

Comment: Are you looking for smth like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w66QRw) ?

Comment: Also, it is unclear why do you use `getProperty` whereas you only provided `setProperty`

Comment: @captain-yossarian Edited question and YES this is actually what I'm looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @captain-yossarian mentioned- solution is

```
enum Property {
    A = 0,
    B,
    C
}

interface PropertyStorage {
    [Property.A]: number;
    [Property.B]: string;
    [Property.C]: boolean;
}

const setProperty = <Name extends keyof PropertyStorage>(name: Name, value: PropertyStorage[Name]) => {

}

setProperty(Property.A, 42)
```

Comment: This is all about inference on function arguments. If you are interested in this topic you can take a look on my article [here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) and [here](https://catchts.com/validators)